# Area enclosed between $x$-axis from $a$ to $b$ and the curve $f(x)$ is finite

Tags: calculus

Area enclosed between $x$-axis from $a$ to $b$ and the curve $f(x)$ is finite when

1. $a=0, \quad b=\infty,\quad f(x)=e^{-5x^5}$
2. $a=-\infty,\quad b=\infty,\quad f(x)=e^{-5x^5}$
3. $a=-7,\quad b=\infty,\quad f(x)=1/x^4$
4. $a=-7,\quad b=7,\quad f(x)=1/x^4$

How can this be solved?

Comment: yes how do you know

Answer (score 4):

Hints:

$$\begin{align*}\bullet&\;\;\;\int\limits_0^\infty e^{-5x^5}dx\le\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\,dx=\lim_{b\to \infty}\left(-\frac1{e^b}+1\right)\ldots\\
\bullet&\;\;\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-5x^5}dx=\int\limits_{-\infty}^0 e^{-5x^5}dx+\int\limits_0^\infty e^{-5x^5}dx\stackrel{\text{subst.:}\;x=-u}=\int\limits_0^\infty\left(e^{5x^5}+e^{-5x^5}\right)dx\;\ldots\\
\bullet&\;\;\int\limits_{-7}^\infty\frac{dx}{x^4}=\int\limits_{-7}^0\frac{dx}{x^4}+\ldots\;:\;\;\text{but}\;\;\int\limits_{-7}^0\frac{dx}{x^4}=-\frac13\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\left(\frac1{\epsilon^3}+\frac1{7^3}\right)=\ldots\end{align*}$$

Comment: Classified solutions +1

Answer (score 1):

As $$\lim_{x\to +\infty}x^5\exp(-5x^5)=0<\infty$$ so according to Comparison test; 1. is convergent and you can evaluate that via definition. But about 4. since $$\lim_{x\to 0^+}(x-0)^4\times \frac{1}{x^4}=1\neq 0$$ and so Comparison test again agrees $$\int_0^1\frac{dx}{x^4}<\int_{-7}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^4}$$ is divergent and so we don't have a finite area in this case.

Comment: why not be option 2

Comment: @santoshkumar: I think for 2 if you consider $\int_{-\infty}^0$ and set $-x=t$ then you get your answer. Try it

Comment: $^++_+^{+_{+_+}}+ _+^+\quad$